# Data-structure to "map" collections to states in a dynamic-programming algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming

I am coding for fun an algorithm to determine the best order of constructing N Building objects. Of course, each Building has its own characteristics (such as a cost, a production, a time of construction, ...). There also exists a total ordering over the Building objects based on those characteristics.

At some point in my dynamic programming I need an adapted data structure to retrieve the best result reached so far to construct k (k<=N) Building. I need this data structure to somehow "map" a collection of the k Building (possibly sorted, since constructing Building b1 and then b2 or b2 and then b1 leaves me with the same N-k buildings but can most likely lead to different states) to the "best-state" reach so far.

I could probably use simple HashMap but it implies repeating a huge number of times collections containing the same elements, not taking into account that [b1,b2] is a sub-collection of [b1,b2,b3,b4] for instance.

I hope I made myself sufficiently clear on that one and I thank you for your help :)

Comment: Not 100% clear on the problem, but perhaps it might be useful to have a class BuildingSet, which can contain objects of both Building and BuildingSet? Then you could have BuildingSet x = [b1, b2] and BuildingSet y = [x, b3, b4].

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to answer without knowing the structure of your solutions.

But, if the solution for k is obtainable from the solution of (k-1) by inserting a building b into position j, then you can have simply an hashmap mapping integer i to the "delta" between the solution for i and the solution for i-1, expressed by a couple.

But having to deal explicitly with deltas can be hideous, because you need to do traversing to get a solution. 
You can solve this by let the delta know the referenced deltas (i.e., passing the delta for (k-1) in the constructor of the delta for k), and then exposing a method `getSolution()` which performs the actual traversing.

You can extend this idea to similar solution structures.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a LinkedHashSet for the key and the value is the cost of building the Buildings contained in the set in its iteration order. It's a bit of a hack but according hashCode and equals it should work. It you prefer to be more explicit go with the hashmap of set to pair of cost and build order.

Answer (score 0):

If your solutions look like ABC,cost1, ABCD,cost2, create a linked list d-> c-> b-> a. Store solutions as tuples of cost and a reference to the last element contained in your Solution (the earliest in the list)